# MotionEvent.getX() and getY() not return correct value

Tags: android, motionevent

The description of the question is in the image below:
[image: Question]

Comment: Can you test it with this app and see if it works well? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rn.yamtt This is to make sure your touch screen driver is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real display area specifies the part of the display that contains content including the system decorations. Even so, the real display area may be smaller than the physical size of the display if the window manager is emulating a smaller display using (adb shell am display-size). Use the following methods to query the real display area: getRealSize(Point), getRealMetrics(DisplayMetrics).

A logical display does not necessarily represent a particular physical display device such as the built-in screen or an external monitor. The contents of a logical display may be presented on one or more physical displays according to the devices that are currently attached and whether mirroring has been enabled.